# Two counters on one page

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling putting three counters on a single page using JavaScript. When I run this page, counters appear but they're freezed, don't refresh. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Counters</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function zero(element) {
      if (element < 10) return element = "0" + element;
      return element;
  }
   
  function counter(day, month, id) {
      var year =  (new Date).getFullYear();
      var today = new Date(); 
      var vDate = new Date(year,month-1,day,9,00); 
      var ms_day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
   
      var diff = (vDate.getTime() - today.getTime()); 
      var e_daysLeft = diff / ms_day; 
      var daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
   
      var e_hoursLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
      var hoursLeft = Math.floor(e_hoursLeft);
   
      var e_minutesLeft = ((e_hoursLeft - hoursLeft)*60);
      var minutesLeft = Math.floor(e_minutesLeft);
   
      var e_secondsLeft = Math.floor((e_minutesLeft - minutesLeft)*60);
      var secondsLeft = Math.floor(e_secondsLeft);
   
      var text = 'Left:  '
                      +daysLeft+' days, '
                      +hoursLeft+ ' hours, '
                      +minutesLeft+ ' minutes '
                      +zero(secondsLeft)+' seconds!'
   
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
   
    
      if (daysLeft+hoursLeft+minutesLeft+secondsLeft <= 0) {
          element.innerHTML = 'Over' ;
      } else {
          element.innerHTML = text;
          setTimeout("counter(day,month,id)",1000)
      }
  }
  counter(14,2,'test7');
  counter(27,3,'test8');
  counter(30,6,'test9');

  </script>

<body onload="counter(14,2,'test7'); counter(27,3,'test8'); counter(30,6,'test9');">

 <div id="test7"></div>
 <div id="test8"></div>
 <div id="test9"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Could you tell me why `setTimeout("counter(day,month,id)",1000)` is not working?

Comment: Isn't t supposed to be `setTimeout(counter(day,month,id),1000)` to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other people have pointed out, you're passing in a string literal rather than a function.

That being said, a typical followup mistake that people often make is writing `setTimeout(counter(day, month, id))`. When you invoke a function (even as a parameter), that function is immediately invoked.  From a runtime perspective, what that ends up looking like is this.

- Call `counter(day, month, id)` and take the returned result of that call.  In your program, this function eventually is going to end up returning `null` once it finishes looping through everything.
- Call `setTimeout(null, 1000)`, passing in the result of `counter(day, month, id)`

Calling `setTimeout(counter(day, month, id))` is really just acting as a shorthand for:

```
var result = counter(day, month, id);
setTimeout(result, 1000);
```

This is why the other answers have suggested wrapping the function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    counter(day, month, id);
}, 1000);
```

This allows you to still pass in all of your parameters to `counter`, while still passing a function with no parameters to setTimeout.

A cleaner solution (at least to me) is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which is kind of like a more convenient shorthand for the above method:

`setTimeout(counter.bind(this, day, month, id), 1000);`

It's outside of the scope of this answer, but the reason I like `bind` is that the parameters will be passed in by value rather than reference, so when using it you're less likely to run into a related common bug involving javascript closures inside of loops. It's just important for you to remember that `bind` is internally very similar conceptually to manually wrapping your methods.

In both instances, you're making a new function that invokes your target function for you with pre-defined parameters, and then passing that new function around rather than your original.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout expects a function, not just a string, have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Here is a modified, working version: https://jsfiddle.net/3todtotp/

Counters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function zero(element) {
        if (element < 10) return element = "0" + element;
        return element;
    }

    function counter(day, month, id) {
        var year =  (new Date).getFullYear();
        var today = new Date(); 
        var vDate = new Date(year,month-1,day,9,00); 
        var ms_day = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 

        var diff = (vDate.getTime() - today.getTime()); 
        var e_daysLeft = diff / ms_day; 
        var daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);

        var e_hoursLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
        var hoursLeft = Math.floor(e_hoursLeft);

        var e_minutesLeft = ((e_hoursLeft - hoursLeft)*60);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor(e_minutesLeft);

        var e_secondsLeft = Math.floor((e_minutesLeft - minutesLeft)*60);
        var secondsLeft = Math.floor(e_secondsLeft);

        var text = 'Left:  '
                        +daysLeft+' days, '
                        +hoursLeft+ ' hours, '
                        +minutesLeft+ ' minutes '
                        +zero(secondsLeft)+' seconds!'

        var element = document.getElementById(id);


        if (daysLeft+hoursLeft+minutesLeft+secondsLeft <= 0) {
            element.innerHTML = 'Over' ;
        } else {
            element.innerHTML = text;
            setTimeout(function(){counter(day,month,id)},1000)
        }
    }
    counter(14,2,'test7');
    counter(27,3,'test8');
    counter(30,6,'test9');

    </script>
```

```
<div id="test7"></div>
<div id="test8"></div>
<div id="test9"></div>
```

Comment: That was the problem :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try setTimeout( function() {counter(day,month,id)},1000) so it's a function which is given to setTimeout not a string.